# Use EF Core to get a list of Longs

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a stored procedure that returns me a list of IDs.  (I then use this list of IDs as keys for objects.)

I am migrating this from .NET to .NET Core.  In normal .NET I could use an extension library to get the numbers out like this:

```
var getOrderDetailIdsStoredProc = new GetOrderDetailIdsStoredProc()
{
    NumberOfOrderDetailIdsNeeded = numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeeded
};

var orderDetailIds = contextProvider.Context.Database
                         .ExecuteStoredProcedure<long>(getOrderDetailIdsStoredProc);
```

But that library (EntityFrameworkExtras) is not working with EF Core (I found a version for EF Core, but it doesn't work.)

So I have been looking for other solutions:

- **DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand**: Cannot return records, only output variables
- **DbSet.FromSQL**: Can only be run on a `DbSet<T>` (basically it needs an entity type)

Right now, all I can think of is to make an entity called `Number`:

```
public class Number
{
    public long Value;
}

public DbSet<Number> Numbers;
```

And then do something like this:

```
Numbers.FromSql("exec GenerateOrderDetailSequencedIds @numberNeeded", numberNeeded)
```

Aside from the fact that this is very ugly (making an entity out of a native type), I have no table to hook it up to, so I worry it will not work.

**Is there any way in EF Core to run a stored procedure and get back a list of numbers?**

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE: This worked, but was not compatable with BreezeJs (it could not deal with a DbQuery).  See my other answer for what I ended up doing.

*OrderDetailIdHolder.cs*

```
public class OrderDetailIdHolder
{
    public long NewId { get; set; }
}
```

*MyEntitiesContext*

```
public DbQuery<OrderDetailIdHolder> OrderDetailIdHolders { get; set; }

internal List<long> GetOrderDetailIds(int numberOfIdsNeeded)
{
    var result = OrderDetailIdHolders.FromSql($"exec Sales.GenerateOrderDetailIds {numberOfIdsNeeded}").ToList();
    return result.Select(x=>x.NewId).ToList(); 
}
```

This a bit extra complexity for just a list of longs.  But it works.

It is important to note that the property (`NewId` in this case) must match what is returned from the sproc.  Also, the type is not a `DbSet`.  It is a `DbQuery`.

It is also important to note that this is only for EF Core 2.2.  EF Core 3 has a different way to do this ([Keyless Entity Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types))

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using:

```
    public static List<T> SqlQueryList<T>(this DatabaseFacade database, string query, params SqlParameter[] sqlParameters)
    {
        // TODO: Add a using statement here so we don't leak the connection's resources.
        var conn = database.GetDbConnection();
        conn.Open();
        var command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters);
        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        List<T> result = new List<T>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            T typedRow;
            var row = reader.GetValue(0);
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                typedRow = (T) row;
            }
            else
            {
                typedRow = (T)Convert.ChangeType(result, typeof(T));
            }

            result.Add(typedRow);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Called like this:

```
var numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeededParam = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeeded",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
};
numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeededParam.Value = numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeeded;
var result = contextProvider.Context.Database.SqlQueryList<long>($"exec Sales.GenerateOrderDetailIds @numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeeded", numberOfOrderDetailIdsNeededParam);
```

I did it this way because it was compatible with BreezeJs for .NET Core.  Note that I only really tested this with Value types.